# Can't we call $result as variable in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have query in my php code

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'delivery')
            or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

        $count = "SELECT MAX(id_pelanggan) FROM pelanggan";

        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $count)
            or die('Error select query');

        if (empty($result)) {
            $id_pelanggan = 1;
        }
        else {
            $id_pelanggan = $result + 1;
        }
```

and the result was

> Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\delivery\addcustomer.php

whereas in mysql id_pelanggan datatype is int.
can anyone help me to make it works?

Comment: you forget to fetch : mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: @HoboSapiens: That's not really true, it's an object (implements `Traversable` and has methods)... it's more like a resource on steroids, if you will

Answer (score 4):

- You try to assign your query to `$id_pelanggan` variable instead of the value from your query.
- Fetch the result using `*_fetch array()` of your query
- I've changed your `if()` condition because your `$result` won't be empty no matter what happens. The number of result maybe.

Put this and replace your `if else` condition:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){ /* IF FOUND 0 RESULT */
  $id_pelanggan = 1;
}

else {

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $maxid = $row["id_pelanggan"];
  }

  $id_pelanggan = $maxid + 1;

} /* END OF ELSE */
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple fetch the result and increment it. You can do this by -

```
    $count = "SELECT MAX(id_pelanggan) as max_id_pelanggan FROM pelanggan";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $count)
        or die('Error select query');

    if (empty($result)) {
        $id_pelanggan = 1;
    }
    else {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        $id_pelanggan = $data['max_id_pelanggan'] + 1;
    }
```